Which critic asserted that English was best when it went against its Germanic roots and followed French habits?
I remember there was a critic, I believe a famous one, who argued that English writing (any writing, but especially literary) was better when it eschewed Germanic habit and followed French/Latin habits.
By Germanic habits they meant long run on sentences and focus on technical jargon. I believe it was Leavis but now I can't find a quote anywhere that supports it.
This is one of those things I read about 40+ years ago, held in my mind as an important idea that affects how I view things (although I tend to be one of those who prefers simple Anglo Saxon words rather than imported ones), now I have need of referring to it and who even knows where I picked it up or if the idea has been warped in my mind.
I have tried googling Leavis and variations of "prefers french literary style". Reading over some stuff by Leavis makes me think it was not him. But it was definitely a critic important in the 40s to early 60s. Which critic was this?

This is strange, because the "fancy" vocabulary we have is imported from French, while Anglo-Saxon words are Germanic. Reminds me of Orwell, but with different labels describing different things, if what you describe is accurate.

I am sure I am describing it inaccurately, read 40 years ago, the argument was not so much about fanciness or simplicity, but rather a feeling of lightness of touch. About the tendency of the language, Germanic languages tend towards stolidity and heaviness, Latin towards wit, imagination, and lightness.  An argument similar to that. But it is so long ago these ideas are not clear in my head anymore, they exist rather as a number of memes that support things I think, but their sources have vanished. Looking for the sources.

So the critic preferred writing that tended towards a more french style and I seem to remember him being described as a francophile for this habit - huh just googling Leavis and Francophile found this https://www.stotesbury-reviews.com/f-r-leavis-the-cambridge-don/  - "I think it would be fair to call him a disliker of Germany but a judicious Francophile,"

French writers eschew run-on sentences? News to me — have you ever tried reading Proust?

@PeterShor yeah I don't remember very well the original thing, just 1950s famous critic, said English was best when it followed French tendencies, eschewed Germanic tendencies, like to find the original argument. It was like a central thing of an argument they made.

@user254694: I believe there is a stereotype that Germans write in long, incomprehensible, run-on sentences. I was just trying to point out that this is an unwarranted generalization, even if it does contain a grain of truth.

I thought the stereotype was That Germans will long, incomprehensible, run on sentences write.
